# Getting a bad value 0 error when generating a PDF

Tags: php, pdf, pdflib

I get this following error when I generate my code:

'Handle parameter or option of type 'page' has bad value 0'

This seems to be the only issue but I can not tell where I am going wrong. Can anyone see an issue here?

```
    {
    $qty = '1000';   

//Open page once
    $indoc = $p->open_pdi_document(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/pdfs/fc/FCMONARCHCKS_b.pdf', "");
    $page = $p->open_pdi_page($indoc, 1, "");
    $width = $p->pcos_get_number($indoc, "pages[0]/width");
    $height = $p->pcos_get_number($indoc, "pages[0]/height");
// Looping thru the start Numbers
    for ($i = $qty; $i >= 0; $i--) {
       if($i == $qty){
          $newNo1 = $this->orderData->check_number + $qty;
      }
      else
      {
       $newNo1 = $newNo1 - 1;
   }



        //Add page that was only opened once
   $p->begin_page_ext($width, $height, "");
   $p->fit_pdi_page($page,0,0,""); 



   $checkNumber_micr = $newNo1;  

   if(strlen($checkNumber_micr) == '3') {
    $newNumber = "00000".$checkNumber_micr;
} elseif(strlen($checkNumber_micr) == '4') {
    $newNumber = "0000".$checkNumber_micr;
} elseif(strlen($checkNumber_micr) == '5') {
    $newNumber = "000".$checkNumber_micr;
} elseif(strlen($checkNumber_micr) == '6') {
    $newNumber = "00".$checkNumber_micr;
} elseif(strlen($checkNumber_micr) == '7') {
    $newNumber = "0".$checkNumber_micr;
}

$check_number ="C".$newNumber."C";
$helper->addTextBlock('check_number_1', $check_number);


$CN1 = $newNumber;
$helper->addTextBlock('CN1', $CN1);

$CN2 = $newNumber;
$helper->addTextBlock('CN2', $CN2);

$CN3 = $newNumber;
$helper->addTextBlock('CN3', $CN3);



$rep ="A121000248A";
$routing_number_1p = $rep;
$helper->addTextBlock('routing_number_1', $routing_number_1p);



$rep2 = "C 4124521923C";
$bank_number_1p = $rep2;
$helper->addTextBlock('bank_account_1', $bank_number_1p);

$p->end_page_ext("");

    }
$p->close_pdi_page($inpage);
}

//Close Page Manually not using helper
$p->end_document("");
$p->close_pdi_document($indoc);
$p->delete();
```

Answer (score 3):

> 'Handle parameter or option of type 'page' has bad value 0'

this is a follow up error. Your open_pdi_document() failed, but you did not check the 
return value. It returns 0 (error), which is not a valid handle and so the open_pdi_page()
failed. 
To solve your problem, please check the return value of the API calls, which return a handle

```
$indoc = $p->open_pdi_document(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/pdfs/fc/FCMONARCHCKS_b.pdf', "");
if ($indoc == 0){
   throw new Exception("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
}
$page = $p->open_pdi_page($indoc, 1, "");
if ($page == 0){
   throw new Exception("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
}
```

(see also the PDFlib samples, which are included in the bind/php directory of the PDFlib package)

During debugging, you can also set "errorpolicy=exception". Please see PDFlib 9.0.2 Tutorial, chapter 3.1.1 "Exception Handling" for a detailed introduction.